# Link SharePoint List Into Access

Tags: sharepoint-online

How in C# can I pass user credentials to SharePoint and link all of the tables for that site into my access database?

For example, with a site address of `http://internalsite.localsite.com/sites/onef/xrz/als/`

How can I link all the lists from that site into my access database from C#?

Answer (score -1):

There is method in access DoCmd.TransferSharePointList - You can use the TransferSharePointList method to import or link data from a SharePoint Foundation site. For SharePoint you can always use CSOM to get all the list from particular site.

By quick googling I found a link which might be useful or give you direction. It would be little tricky though but see how can you best utilize above method.

```
Dim objTable As Object



For Each objTable In CurrentDb.TableDefs

   If Left(objTable.Name, 4) <> "Msys" Then

       DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "WSS", Me.txtSitePath, acTable, objTable.Name, objTable.Name

       DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, objTable.Name

       DoCmd.TransferSharePointList acLinkSharePointList, Me.txtSitePath, objTable.Name, , objTable.Name

   End If

Next objTable
```

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other/linking-to-sharepoint-list-from-ms-access/75c31c75-6d99-4c43-b40a-a7281431c6c3

Comment: This shows how to use DoCmd.TransferSharePointList to link the table into access, but how can the credentials be passed when linking?